# Communicate/Transfer a java class output value to a text field in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

i got a java class **ipaddr** program which holds the ip address of a local host.... and other is a **loginpage.jsp**... i need to include the java
class ipaddr output in a **hidden text field** which wil fetch the ip address along with username and password...can anyone explain with a simple 
source code...how to **communicate a java class output value to a text field in jsp**...or **how to import the value of ipaddr program to jsp page**
thanks for ur time,
regards,
dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If IPAddress is dynamic[i.e, which is extracted during run time ] you can declare a instance method, which returns IpAddress

If IPAddress is static, declare it as public static variable

After which the value can be called directly in JSP

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%=InetAddress.getLocalHost()%>"/>
```

Do not forget to import java.net.InetAddress in the beginning of your jsp:

```
<%@ page import="java.net.InetAddress;" %>
```

(If you are using custom tag libraries it depends on your tag library.)

Comment: Alex i have assigned the value to a string.... in ipaddr... i need to fetch the value from that string to the jsp page